# open a bootstrap tab ( thats within an accordion ) from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a list of tabs that is situated inside an accordion and I would like to open a specific tab from a link that is on another page. I have found a piece of javascript that allows me top open a specific accordion panel from another page, which is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  location.hash && $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
});
```

but this obviously won't work for a list of tabs inside the accordion.

here is one of the links on the action page..

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="window.open('information.php?acc=private-body&tab=pri-faq' , 'faq-window' , 'width=980,height=600,top=100, left=500,toolbar=no')">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
```

Here is some of the html on the page that opens in the new browser window: ( I have removed most of the list and accordion items the reduce this sample)

```
<head>
<script>
function getUrlParameter(variable)
{
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split("&");
for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
       if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
}
return(false);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var accordian = getUrlParameter("acc");
var tab = getUrlParameter("tab");
$('#' + accordian + '.collapse').collapse('show');
$('#' + accordian + ' #' + tab).tab('show');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="accordion" id="private">
<div class="private accordion-group accordion-caret">
  <div class="main accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#private" href="#private-body">Information for private residential properties</a> </div>
  <div id="private-body" class="accordion-body collapse">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#pri-process" data-toggle="tab">The Right to Manage process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pri-faq" data-toggle="tab">Frequently Asked Qustions</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="pri-process">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
    <ol>
    <li>....  </li> 
  </ol>
    </div><!-- END SPAN6_01-->
    <div class="span6">
    <ol start="7">
    <li>....  </li>
    </ol>
    </div><!-- END SPAN6_02-->
    </div><!-- END ROW FLUID -->

    </div><!-- END TAB PANE -->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="pri-faq">
    <div class="accordion" id="pri-faq-accordion">
<div class="accordion-group accordion-caret">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#pri-faq-    accordion" href="#pri-Qone">1. What is the Right to Manage?</a>
</div>
<div id="pri-Qone" class="accordion-body collapse">
<div class="accordion-inner">
<p>....  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"  href="#pri-Qtwo">2. What is the purpose of Right to Manage?</a>
</div>
<div id="pri-Qtwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
<div class="accordion-inner">
<p>....  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- END PRI-FAQ ACCORDION -->
    </div><!-- END TAB PANE -->
    </div><!-- END TAB CONTENT -->
    </div><!-- END ACCORDION INNER -->
  </div><!-- END ACCORDION GROUP -->
</div>
</div><!-- END PRIVATE INFO ACCORDION -->
</body>
```

so I would like to open the tab pane #pri-process which is inside #private-body accordion panel. And I would like to do this from another page on the web-site.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that works is because it is using the ID as a parameter. Now you need to pass 2 parameters to the next page, it might be better to use url parameters. The first parameter needs to be the id of the accordian panel, and the second parameter needs to be the id of the link to the tab you want to open. This means you will need to add IDs to your tab links. I have made a bootply for you to show what it should look like. I have hard coded the variables in the javascript section, as I was unsure if you can use variables like that in bootply, so use the javascript in this answer, not the link.

Anyway, your tab links need ids like so

```
<li><a href="#pri-faq" id="faq-link" data-toggle="tab">Frequently Asked Qustions</a></li>
```

Here is the javascript

```
function getUrlParameter(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}

$document.ready(function() {
    var accordian = getUrlParameter("acc");
    var tab = getUrlParameter("tab");
    $('#' + accordian + '.collapse').collapse('show');
    $('#' + accordian + ' #' + tab).tab('show');
});
```

As a side note, you do not need to use window.open, you can instead use a normal anchor and change the target to `_blank` like in the following link. The link to open the popup should look something like this:

```
<a href="page.html?acc=private-body&tab=faq-link" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: Can't get this to work WaxMann. I'm wanting to open in a new window so my link currently is: `<a onClick="window.open('information.php?acc=private-body&tab=pri-process' ,'process-window' , 'width=900,height=600,top=100, left=500,toolbar=no')">The Right to Manage process</a>` I have pasted your script example into the results page. Is this wrong?

Comment: The script I gave should be placed on the information.php page somewhere. I would need more information to find out why it is not working though. If you open developer tools (press F12) are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I noticed you had missing brackets around 'document' like this: `$document.ready(function() )` I corrected this in my code but still not working. I am about to revise my sample code above to show you what I have.

Comment: I have found your problem. The id for the tab parameter needs to be the ID for the link to open the tab, not for the tab itself. I will update my answer for you.